# How do I center a Theme background image in an Android activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I've wasted a ton of time on this, and of all the "answers" I've seen searching, none work. Basically, I just want a bitmap to be centered horizontally in the theme, then repeating vertically. No matter what I do, it's always left-aligned. I've tried it in code, and in XML. Here's what I'm using right now:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:label="MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeName" />
```

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ThemeName" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/xml_bitmap</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**res/drawable/xml_bitmap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/png_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

To help clarify, I've also tried setting the background to the bitmap in code like so:

```
Resources r = getResources();
Drawable d = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.xml_bitmap);
getListView().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

This gives the exact same result; leading me to believe something is wrong in the xml_bitmap.xml file. From what I've read in the docs, there's not many other options, and what I have would SEEM to be correct: [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)

Comment: show the main.xml main layout, please.

Comment: The activity in question (MyActivity) is actually a ListActivity, so I don't have a custom layout, I just let Android do its thing.